# Select first text between two expressions

Tags: regex

I want to return the **first** "abcd" part of the text below.

```
 00abcd126456\x 00abcd126456\x
```

I want to select all text between the first " 00" and the first (6 digits + "\x"). Every string starts with " 00".

I've been experementing with:

```
^ 00(.*)\d{6}\\x
```

but it obviously selects the whole string.

Please help.

Comment: this site might help: http://txt2re.com/

Comment: Probably helpful, but I can't get it to work like I want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a non-greedy quantifier:

```
^ 00(.*?)\d{6}\\x
```

`*?` will only match *as few as possible* characters to allow the match to succeed, instead of `*` which will match *as many characters as possible*.

If you don't want to fiddle around with the capturing group you can also use lookaround:

```
(?<=^ 00).*?(?=\d{6}\\x)
```

Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS> ' 00abcd126456\x 00abcd126456\x' -match '(?<=^ 00).*?(?=\d{6}\\x)'; $Matches
True

Name                           Value
----                           -----
0                              abcd
```

Comment: Cool, that solves half of the problem. But I only want the "abcd" part.

Comment: @Skalis, the "abcd" part is in capturing group 1

Comment: @stema Thx, but I'm _that_ new - I don't know what capturing group 1 is. I'm guessing it's some sort of sub query? Going to read up on it.

Comment: Usually you get some kind of match object where you can access the groups by number or name.

Comment: @Joey, yeah I noticed. For examle match.Groups[1].Value in c#. Problem is this is to be used in a already written business application. I'm gooing to mark the question answered.

Comment: lookaround generates no matches though :)

Comment: It works for me in PowerShell which also uses .NET's regex support.

Comment: Ah, I guess it's the javascript based testers that have problems. Thanks!